# Pexpect ssh option StrictHostKeyChecking raising TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, pexpect

I have a python script that ssh into a device using the `pexpect` module. It essentially runs the following

```
$ ssh hostname -l username
```

by doing:

```
>>> import pexpect.pxssh as pxssh
>>> conn = pxssh.pxssh()
>>> conn.login(hostname, username, password, terminal_type='vt100')
>>> ...
```

Now, I am trying to implemement the same script with the `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` option. In order to do this, I follow the [documentation](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pxssh.html) of `pexpect` and add `options={}` as below. However, it raises the following `TypeError`.

```
>>> import pexpect.pxssh as pxssh
>>> conn = pxssh.pxssh(options={'StrictHostKeyChecking':'no',})
Exception AttributeError: "'pxssh' object has no attribute 'closed'" in <bound method pxssh.__del__ of <pexpect.pxssh.pxssh object at 0x7f96294aded0>> ignored
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'
```

I have had a look around and I could not find a solution to this problem. Is this a known problem, and if it is, is there any hack?

My setup is the following:

```
>>> print pexpect.__version__
3.1
```

which seems to be the last version as

```
$ apt-cache policy python-pexpect
python-pexpect:
  Installed: 3.1-1ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 3.1-1ubuntu0.1
```

Comment: `options = dict(StrictHostKeyChecking="no",)`

Comment: @Ajay to be clear, you suggests `>>> options = dict(StrictHostKeyChecking="no",); conn = pxssh.pxssh(options)';`

Comment: yes that's what i meant

Answer (score 0):

With current pexpect versions passing ssh config options works as documented.

For example, the following works fine with pexpect-4.3 (using Python 3.6/Linux):

```
s = pxssh.pxssh(options={
    'StrictHostKeyChecking': 'yes',
    'HostKeyAlgorithms': 'ssh-ed25519',
    'UserKnownHostsFile': 'known-horsts',
    },
    timeout=3)
s.login('example.org', 'juser')
```